# Does Jenkins support XML Canon?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, devops, tibco

Can I using Jenkins to get sources and build project stored on XML Canon (Tibco projects) ?

Does Jenkins support XML Canon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TIBCO XML Canon™/Developer (XCD)](https://edelivery.tibco.com/storefront/eval/tibco-xml-canon/prod10049.html)  is a design-time repository to manage the development and deployment of XML assets (e.g. XML schemas, DTDs, adjuncts, instance documents, and style sheets) utilizing a Web-based interface.

As long as you can get the source and build from command-line, you can reuse those same command lines from a Jenkins job.

In other words, there is no direct Jenkins plugin doing what you need to with a Tibco XML Canon project.
But if you can do it manually, then integrating that process in a Jenkins job is trivial.